# The functional equation $f(-x+b)=f(x)$

Tags: functional-equations, periodic-functions, fractional-part

I can solve the (periodic) functional equation $f(x+b)=f(x)$  completely ($x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\neq 0$). Indeed,
its general solution is $f=\phi o (\; )_b$, where $(\; )_b$ is the $b$-decimal (fractional) part function defined by 
$$(\; )_b(x) =(x)_b:=x-b\lfloor \frac{x}{b}\rfloor,$$
(see http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-19/NNTDM-19-4-04-15.pdf) and $\phi$ every real function defined on $b[0,1)$. In general, it is solved on arbitrary groups (see http://www.ijmex.com/index.php/ijmex/article/viewFile/194/115).

Now, can somebody solve the functional equation  $f(-x+b)=f(x)$?
(is there such a general solution for it?)

Comment: Note that the map $-x+b$ maps the interval $(b/2,+\infty)$ bijectively onto the interval $(-\infty,b/2)$.  So: define $f$ any way you like on $[b/2,+\infty)$, and use the functional equation to extend the definition to $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Define $y = x - b/2$. Then every even function in $y$ satisfies your equation.

Comment: What is general form of the even functions?

Comment: A function is called "even" if it has the property $f(-x) = f(x)$. For example the cosine function or $x^2$ or the absolute value of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, I know, I said the general form. Also,  $y=x-b/2$ doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this functional equation belongs to the form of http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe1113.pdf.

The general solution is $f(x)=\Theta(x,b-x)$ , where $\Theta(u,v)$ is any symmetric function.